# Django - Python: submit a form, do not refresh the page, get data from the form submitted

Tags: python, django

i have a form in my homepage (index.html):

```
<form  action="{% url "..." %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="custom-form-thing">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="inputWrapper">
        <input id="some_file_input" type="file"  name="some_file" class="custom-input-thing">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My website is in one page, meaning that i move around with arrows in both sides of the screen to go to the other pages. This 2 arrows are hidden when the user gets to the index page and they only appear after the user submits his/her file in the form, after that he /she can move around to the other pages

When the form is submitted in the back there are a few methods that start to run and do some work on the file submitted and return a bunch of data that i display in the page to the right of the index page, About.html

What i am trying to do is to submit the form and just stay there but use the data that those methods return to complete the About.html page

What i am doing right now is to redirect to that same index.html in my view:

```
def method():
    ...
    return render(request,  'App/index.html',context={'dates': dates})
```

and in my form:

```
<form  action="{% url "index" %}"...>
```

The problem with this is that when i submit the form the page refreshes(sorry for my english) so the hidden arrows are hidden again and the user can not move around  to see the data in the About page.

so the question is: How can i submit the form and just stay in the index.html without refreshing the page.

Very long text for a simple question, just wanted to give you guys the context of why i want to do this

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit**

i know nothing about ajax or jquery so if there is an answer that suggest the usage of both please take in count that

Comment: I would look into sending an ajax request on the button click to the desired web page address and use the ajax `success` function to change the page. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to send data to your form handler, and handle the returned data in your javascript.

If you want to use the submit button, and submit the form to your index, assign a value to your DJANGO template when a POST request is made, and add the class that you use to show them if it is assigned.

Comment: I understand part of what u suggest, can you please elavorate with a code snippet? cause i know nothing at all about ajax or javascript or jquery. Thanks